# Linking Polycode to C++

Tags: c++, cmake

How can I use Polycode as a framework for c++ on Linux? I know I have to include header files and link the libraries so I can use the built in functions and classes of Polycode but there are way too many files scattered around. Is there an easier way to link all of the Polycode contents so C++ can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [instructions](https://github.com/ivansafrin/Polycode/blob/master/BUILD.md). You will need CMake and various libraries you'll need to install first, such as Ogg Vorbis and Bullet Physics. After CMake does its job, it put should everything into a `Release` subdirectory.

Unfortunately the instructions don't seem so clear about what will be there… but you should be able to copy `include` and `lib` subdirectories from there to `/usr/local` so you don't need to manually set compiler flags for your C++ environment to access it.

Note, it doesn't look so mature, so you might be careful, and don't hesitate to contact the author.